# How to create Animation video from Images like Google photos?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am working on a mobile application to create a video/animation of multiple images.
I have used server side tools like ffmpeg and whammy, what are other server side or mobile open source tools that i can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Andorid you can take a look at Intel Media for Mobile with samples on github:
https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile

it is able to join videos and apply jpegs above videos